# Queue- Multi Threading Python

Tags: python, multithreading, variables, queue, pyserial

I have a bunch of code and I am attaching a piece here. Basically I have a thread - which is targeted on a function - that has a while loop as following :

```
while not stop_event.wait(1): # Continuous Reading Function

    #print "hello2"
    #print ("working on %s" % arg)
    data1 = Read(soa1, bytes1, ser)
    data2 = Read(soa2, bytes2, ser)
    data3 = Read(soa3, bytes3, ser)

    data = np.concatenate([data1, data2, data3])
    print data.size
    queue_read.put(data)
    time.sleep(1)
```

I am reading the data from an MCU, through serial communication in this thread and sending it back to my Main program - using queue_read.put(data). This while is ran every 1 second.

In my main program I am reading the output from this thread as ---

```
self.data = queue_read.get()
```

After five minutes the values in the MCU are intentionally changed. During the change this thread is still running as it is in while loop.

So after five minutes, the variable "data" should have the updated new values from the MCU. But to my surprise it does not. It still has the initial values. Is there anything I am missing here? Is using queue, the right way to get data?

Comment: `Queue` is ideal for producer/consumer threads. But we need to see what `enter code here` is in the OP in order to help

Comment: @CraigBurgler I edited the question. The problem is self.data or the variable "data" is not getting updated, because once my main program went through the line of code self.data = queue_read.get(), it wont read again. So I am wondering how should I be able to read data from thread continuosly and update my GUI

Comment: please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

The following approach reads and processes data from the queue continuously, which allows you to see and respond to data changes as they happen:

```
while True:
    self.data = queue_read.get()
    self.update_GUI()
```

`queue_read.get()` blocks if `queue_read` is empty. You will need to run this code in its own thread if the main thread does anything other than update the GUI.